# how to resolve cors policy problems with react and nginx

Tags: express, nginx

When I try to launch my expresssjs serverwith pm2 on nginx and I go to the path /login , I get those errors:

> Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. node.js:401
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
> Login error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. index-ad8a4f2f.js:102:24347